# AddChild and removeChild in ActionScript 3 does not work properly

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am wondering that why I get `Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference` by using removeChild() function in my as3 code which is as following:

```
public class MyGame extends MovieClip{

    private var myMovieClip:MovieClip;

    public function add():void{
        myMovieClip = new MyMovieClip();
        addChild(myMovieClip);
    }

    public function remove():void{
        removeChild(myMovieClip);
    }
```

}

in the remove function, I wanna remove myMovieClip object and then create a new one and use it for continuing of my application.

Any idea will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It appears that myMovieClip is null at the time you are calling remove...

This might be a little safer

```
function DetachFromParent(mc:MovieClip):void
{
   if(mc!= null && mc.parent != null)
   {
       mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not that, because my object extended from MovieClip shows something in stage and if I use immediately removeChild() function after addChild() that thing will be disappear, but the problem is that I wanna remove my movieClip in another function(removeChild in example above) . Thanks

Comment: Generally that error would only get thrown in this instance if either myMovieClip == null, or if myMovieClip.parent != this or if myMovieClip.parent == null.  Which is why this function should account for all of these behaviors...

Comment: Yes I know, but my question is what is the problem exactly, I should add that I added your function in my code but I got exactly the same error

Comment: There is something else strange going on then here, can you provide a small example project fla with the error?

Comment: I am going to provide a simple version

Comment: Thanks again for your response, I got the error. The problem was about my object which I used, in that class I had added stage.addChild(...), that's why I got error CANNOT ACCESS A PROPERTY.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you even need to remove `myMovieClip`:

```
public function remove():void{
    if(myMovieClip) // myMovieClip is not null or undefined, remvove it
        removeChild(myMovieClip);
}
```

Comment: As JTtheGeek said, You also need to check that myMovieClip has a parent. Otherwise, he second call to remove() would result in the null pointer.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not that, because my object extended from MovieClip shows something in stage and if I use immediately removeChild() function after addChild() that thing will be disappear, but the problem is that I wanna remove my movieClip in another function(removeChild in example above) . Thanks